# How to properly use popToViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

What I am trying to do, is to pop all previous view controllers from the stack up to the 'menu' controller. I have a piece of code that is supposed to do that, but when 'menu' is clicked, the app crashes.

The reason for the crash: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'

Here is part of my code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // 0 = menu
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]
        let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
        let _ = navigationController?.popToViewController(viewController!, animated: true)

    } else {

        let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]
        let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't instantiate a *new instance* of the view controller you are trying to pop to; you need to pop to the *actual instance* that is in the navigation stack.

If your menu is the root of your navigation stack then you can use `popToRootViewController`.  If it is somewhere else in the stack then you either need to hold a reference to it or you can iterate through the navigation controller's `viewControllers` array to find it and then pop to it.

```
if let navController = self.navigationController {
    for controller in navController.viewControllers {
        if controller is MenuController { // Change to suit your menu view controller subclass
            navController.popToViewController(controller, animated:true)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's somewhere else in the stack (not a root), can you show me how to access it using a reference in code? Just to minimize the amount of questions I have.

Comment: Thanks! I did just that, and it worked perfectly. And easily implemented.